# Cocos2d 2.0 worked code not working in Cocos2d 2.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

In my project below code used. It worked in iOS9 - Cocos2d 2.0. Now in Cocos2d 2.2 same code not working...no crash but platform image not coming...How to fix this for Cocos2d 2.2 ?

```
-(CCSprite *)stripedSpriteWithColor1:(ccColor4F)c1 color2:(ccColor4F)c2 textureWidth:(float)textureWidth
textureHeight:(float)textureHeight stripes:(int)nStripes {

    // 1: Create new CCRenderTexture
    CCRenderTexture *rt = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:textureWidth height:textureHeight];

    // 2: Call CCRenderTexture:begin
    [rt beginWithClear:c1.r g:c1.g b:c1.b a:c1.a];

    // 3: Draw into the texture

    // Layer 1: Stripes
    CGPoint vertices[nStripes*6];
    ccColor4F colors[nStripes*6];

    int nVertices = 0;
    float x1 = -textureHeight;
    float x2;
    float y1 = textureHeight;
    float y2 = 0;
    float dx = textureWidth / nStripes * 2;
    float stripeWidth = dx/2;
    for (int i=0; i<nStripes; i++) {
        x2 = x1 + textureHeight;

        vertices[nVertices] = CGPointMake(x1, y1);
        colors[nVertices++] = (ccColor4F){c2.r, c2.g, c2.b, c2.a};

        vertices[nVertices] = CGPointMake(x1+stripeWidth, y1);
        colors[nVertices++] = (ccColor4F){c2.r, c2.g, c2.b, c2.a};

        vertices[nVertices] = CGPointMake(x2, y2);
        colors[nVertices++] = (ccColor4F){c2.r, c2.g, c2.b, c2.a};

        vertices[nVertices] = vertices[nVertices-2];
        colors[nVertices++] = (ccColor4F){c2.r, c2.g, c2.b, c2.a};

        vertices[nVertices] = vertices[nVertices-2];
        colors[nVertices++] = (ccColor4F){c2.r, c2.g, c2.b, c2.a};

        vertices[nVertices] = CGPointMake(x2+stripeWidth, y2);
        colors[nVertices++] = (ccColor4F){c2.r, c2.g, c2.b, c2.a};
        x1 += dx;
    }

    self.shaderProgram =
    [[CCShaderCache sharedShaderCache] programForKey:kCCShader_PositionColor];

    CCSprite *noise;
    noise = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"FarmBase.png"];
    [noise setBlendFunc:(ccBlendFunc){GL_DST_COLOR, GL_ZERO}];
    noise.position = ccp(textureWidth/2, textureHeight/2);
    [noise visit];
    [rt end];

    // 5: Create a new Sprite from the texture
    return [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:rt.sprite.texture];
}
```

**UPDATES:**
Here is solution for shaders problem in cocos2d v2.2 [Shader Program not working in Cocos2d 2.2 Obj.C iOS 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55104186/shader-program-not-working-in-cocos2d-2-2-obj-c-ios-12)

Comment: Why did you use CCRenderTexture instead of using cc.RenderTexture?

Comment: @komeilmajidi its Cocos2d 2.0 old code created during 2014. Now we used Cocos2d 2.2 and other things working...cc.RenderTexture not available in Cocos2d 2.2 right ?