# Shader Program not working in Cocos2d 2.2 Obj.C iOS 12

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

CODE:

```
  [lightRender beginWithClear:0 g:0 b:0 a:0];

    self.shaderProgram = [[CCShaderCache sharedShaderCache] programForKey:kCCShader_PositionColor];

    CC_NODE_DRAW_SETUP();

    CGPoint vertices[3];
    ccColor4F colors[3];

    CGPoint mid = BODY_POSITION(cursor.body);

    float radius = LIGHT_RANGE * lightRadius;             // - (CCRANDOM_0_1() * LIGHT_RANGE * .015);

    float initialAlpha = .7f;

    for (int i = 0; i < LIGHT_PRECISION; i++)
    {
        int nVertices = 0;
        float angle = 2*M_PI/LIGHT_PRECISION * i;
        float nextAngle = 2*M_PI/LIGHT_PRECISION * (i+1);
        int n = i + 1;
        if (n == LIGHT_PRECISION)
            n = 0;

        vertices[nVertices] = ccpAdd(mid, ccp(cosf(angle) * radius * lightLength[i], sinf(angle) * radius * lightLength[i]));
        colors[nVertices++] = (ccColor4F){1, 1, .9, initialAlpha * (1 - lightLength[i])};
        vertices[nVertices] = ccpAdd(mid, ccp(cosf(nextAngle) * radius * lightLength[n], sinf(nextAngle) * radius * lightLength[n]));
        colors[nVertices++] = (ccColor4F){1, 1, .9, initialAlpha * (1 - lightLength[n])};
        vertices[nVertices] = mid;
        colors[nVertices++] = (ccColor4F){1, 1, .8, initialAlpha};

        ccGLEnableVertexAttribs(kCCVertexAttribFlag_Position  | kCCVertexAttribFlag_Color);

        glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_Position, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, vertices);
        glVertexAttribPointer(kCCVertexAttrib_Color, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, colors);
        glBlendFunc(CC_BLEND_SRC, CC_BLEND_DST);
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, (GLsizei)nVertices);
    }

    [lightRender end];
```

CC_NODE_DRAW_SETUP Code:

```
#define CC_NODE_DRAW_SETUP()                                                                    \
do {                                                                                            \
    ccGLEnable( _glServerState );                                                               \
    NSAssert1(_shaderProgram, @"No shader program set for node: %@", self);                     \
    [_shaderProgram use];                                                                       \
    [_shaderProgram setUniformsForBuiltins];                                    \
} while(0)
```

How to fix shader code in iOS12 with Cocos2d 2.2 Obj.C project ? If I run in iOS 7 simulator it works perfect..same code not working in iOS 12

Answer (score 1):

Fixed Shaders Problem in Cocos2d.

In Above code, main problem is CGFloat...converted it to float for all vertices.

Also I took shaders related files from Cocos2d-x and converted it to obj.C for Cocos2d.

Now all shaders working Perfect in Cocos2d v2.2 Obj.C iOS 12, iPhoneX/XR/XSMax also..

Happy Coding! Cheers :)